# Having trouble installing molecular add-on

Tags: add-on

This might be a stupid question but I am having trouble finding the molecular add-on once I have downloaded it. I am trying to follow the instructions in this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ym8XDXZrdw

but I don't see the add-on when I try to install it. I have saved tried saving it to a few different places but it doesn't appear anywhere. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Location in the UI**

The usual place is in the Particle Properties tab in the Properties Editor. You have to have an object and a particle system created:

[image]

**Installation**

> I have saved tried saving it to a few different places but it doesn't
> appear anywhere.

Just in case you are struggling with installation, you should not copy anything anywhere. Just download the zip file, and choose it in the Preferences, Add-ons tab after clicking "Install..." button:

[image]

Installation process should automatically input its name into search field for you at the end so you can enable it once its' installed.